Is ELISA analysis in Elixir Nx/Schorar possible?
I have read the article ELISA Analysis in Python on Medium.
The above article uses SciPy's curve_fit function to find an approximate curve based on the 4 parameter logistic regression (4PL) model as follows:
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [1.95, 3.91, 7.381, 15.63, 31.25, 62.5, 125,250, 500, 1000]
y = [0.274, 0.347, 0.392, 0.420, 0.586, 1.115, 1.637, 2.227, 2.335, 2.372]

def log4pl(x, A, B, C, D):
    return(((A - D) / (1.0 + ((x / C) ** B))) + D)

params, _ = curve_fit(log4pl, x, y)
A, B, C, D = params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]

I would like to do the same thing using the Nx/Scholar library in Elixir.
Is it possible? I would appreciate any hints you can give me.

[UPDATE]
From a quick look at the Python scipy.optimize source code, it appears that curve_fit uses Fortran's MINPACK library internally.
As far as I know, there is no easy way to use MINPACK from Elixir.
Therefore, I conclude that it is difficult to do ELISA Analysis in Elixir at this time.
I welcome any additional information.

Scholar uses Polaris.Optimizers in the backend. This is gradient based optimizer which can be used to optimize custom functions. For me by checking how optimizer works for Scholar logistic regression it should be possible to tune it for your problem: https://github.com/elixir-nx/scholar/blob/main/lib/scholar/linear/logistic_regression.ex Sry, don't have more time to work on your question Today, but basically it is doable. Hope my answer will inspire smn.

It looks like Ryo Wakabayashi implemented a way to do it:
https://qiita.com/RyoWakabayashi/items/ff68bb9313c2c30f3b10


With the advice of Mr. Wakabayashi, I was able to solve this problem using Nx.
The function FPL.update/4, which is the base of machine learning, is shown below:
defmodule FPL do
  import Nx.Defn

  defnp loss_fn({a, b, c, d}, x, y) do
    y_pred = log4pl(x, a, b, c, d)
    Nx.mean(Nx.pow(y_pred - y, 2))
  end

  defnp log4pl(x, a, b, c, d) do
    ((a - d) / (1.0 + Nx.pow(x / c, b)) + d)
  end

  defn update({a, b, c, d} = params, x, y, lr) do
    {grad_a, grad_b, grad_c, grad_d} = grad(params, &loss_fn(&1, x, y))
    {a - grad_a * lr,  b - grad_b * lr, c - grad_c * lr * 1000, d - grad_d * lr}
  end
end

Using this function, we can obtain the parameters of the approximate curve as follows:
x = Nx.tensor([1.95, 3.91, 7.381, 15.63, 31.25, 62.5, 125.0, 250.0, 500.0, 1000.0])
y = Nx.tensor([0.274, 0.347, 0.392, 0.420, 0.586, 1.115, 1.637, 2.227, 2.335, 2.372])

epochs = 2500
lr = 0.05

{a, b, c, d} = {Nx.tensor(1.0), Nx.tensor(1.0), Nx.tensor(1.0), Nx.tensor(1.0)}

acc =
  Enum.reduce(1..epochs, {a, b, c, d}, fn _epoch, acc ->
    FPL.update(acc, x, y, lr)
  end)

{a, b, c, d} = acc
a = Nx.to_number(a)
b = Nx.to_number(b)
c = Nx.to_number(c)
d = Nx.to_number(d)

The actual values of the parameters obtained are as follows:
a = 0.31874406337738037
b = 1.787353754043579
c = 85.46488952636719
d = 2.420581579208374

This result is quite close to the original article.
Note that Mr. Wakabayashi said that normalization of the data would make the learning process more efficient.
